# Does using Ghostery with Privacy Badger impair PB's heuristic learning?

Tags: privacy, firefox, tracking

I am running Ghostery and Privacy Badger for FF.

From what I have read at eff.org/privacybadger, PB uses a heuristic algorithm to learn what 3rd-party sites are tracking me. If I am running Ghostery at the same time, does that prevent PB from learning?

If Ghostery does inhibit PB's learning, that presents me with a potential "catch-22". I don't want to let trackers slip through while PB is learning, but I would like PB to get to a level where I would no longer find Ghostery necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no - the sites blocked by ghostery (or other ad/tracker blockers like uBlock or Disconnect) won't be picked up by Privacy Badger, meaning that they won't get included in its heuristics. At the same time this means that they are successfully getting blocked - by your other ad/tracker blocker.

This means that Privacy Badger will catch all the things that don't trigger the block lists on your ad blockers. If you turn off your ad blocker then there will suddenly be new third parties that Privacy Badger hasn't seen before and it will take it a few visits to flag these as trackers. But if you use the same ad/tracker blocker regularly you shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Welcome! it might help to disclose who you are... :)

Comment: On the options page the frame showing trackers is very small and cannot be sized. It takes too long to scroll through the list. Is there a way to see all trackers at once? Is this in db or sqlite somewhere?

Comment: I found Options>Manage Data tab allows download of user data in json. I am able to parse that to find what I want, but this is a static view of data that changes constantly. Would be nice to interface directly with the data. Is there a way to do that?